# Find amount of happy numbers in a given range

Tags: java

I need to find all happy numbers in a given range (input)

A happy number is a number which eventually reaches 1 when replaced by the sum of the square of each digit. 13 is a happy number because 1^2 + 3^2 = 10 And 1^2 + 0^2 = 1, thus 13 is a happy number.

So far I have this:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String wrd = scan.nextLine().trim();
    String wrd2 = scan.nextLine().trim();

    int nieuwnummer = Integer.parseInt(wrd);
    int nieuwnummer2 = Integer.parseInt(wrd2);

    // int count = 0
    
    Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = nieuwnummer; i <= nieuwnummer2; i++) { while(nieuwnummer>0) {
                nieuwnummer2 += (nieuwnummer % 10)*(nieuwnummer % 10); 
                nieuwnummer /=10; };
            }
      
            nieuwnummer = nieuwnummer2;
        }
      //System.out.println(count)
    
  }
```

I think the range isn't working yet and I need a way to actually count the happy number. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly but:

You have `while(nieuwnummer > 0)` which is some number on start but after first loop it is changing to 0 [ eg. if range is from 1 to 16] so it will go one time and then skip.

For that kind of problem I would use something like this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lucky-numbers/

and iterate over the loop

Answer (score 0):

Here is some working example.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String st1 = scan.nextLine().trim();
        String st2 = scan.nextLine().trim();

        int min = Integer.parseInt(st1);
        int max = Integer.parseInt(st2);

        Set<Integer> happyNumbers = getHappyNumbers(min, max);
        System.out.println(happyNumbers.size());

    }

    public static Set<Integer> getHappyNumbers(int min, int max) {
        Set<Integer> out = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = min; i < max; i++) {
            if (isHappy(i)) {
                out.add(i);
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    private static boolean isHappy(int i) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (i != 0) {
            sum += Math.pow((i % 10), 2);
            i /= 10;
        }
        if (sum == 1) return true;
        else if (sum >= 10) {return isHappy(sum);}
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I got 20 errors from testing this; am I doing it incorrectly? Your code does seem pretty good so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: @LucasWinkel  20 errors! Did you do the imports?

Comment: @LucasWinkel I have added all the imports needed for me. Please check the answer again.

Comment: Okay so the code does work. I have tested it in the site that my teacher told me to test it in. The code worked perfectly in 7 out of the 10 tests. Unfortunately I can't see what tests they did. Ill ask my teacher about it tomorrow, but is there at the moment anything you can do to fix it? If not, then you still have my thanks for all your effort.

Comment: @LucasWinkel if you can tell me what are the test cases that this failed, I can help you.

Comment: I am doing a national test which I need to make this for. There are 5 exercises (one of them is this one). The deadline for all 5 of them combined is in about 100 days. I need to download the code and insert it in a specific site that checks the code in 10 cases. They won't show me those cases because that way it would be easy to counter them. Ill ask my teacher tomorrow but if you don't hear from me again, it'll be because I can't know the other test cases. But thank you.